# DjangoRestFramework - URI with multiple items (cross between a list view and a detail view)

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.1

django 2.1, python 3.6.

I have a list of items that could contain duplicates. When I pass it to the model and use the in filter, it removes the duplicates . Is there anyway to return a query set with each item in the list instead of each item in the deduped list

```
card_list = [1,1,2,3]    
qs = Card.objects.filter(id__in=card_list)
```

`qs.count()` yields 3
I is there a better command to use that 'in' or a way to join it back to the origial list so I can return with a 4 item queryset?

Thanks